# ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 load balancing

Tags: arcgis-server, f5

We have ArcGIS server 9.3.1 which already have load balancing (SOM) and F5 hardware load balancing. Is it good practices to have both of them working or to use only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

SOM already have load balancing like round robin. F5 will never knows about Soc failuer, thus you need to use some F5 confguration to check if the SOC is working fine, see the F5 manual to see how this can be done